# Nginx reverse proxy mapping does not redirect

Tags: node.js, nginx, centos, reverse-proxy, portforwarding

I recently started tinkering to solve this problem I was having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60246745/routing-a-web-address-to-a-ipport-in-centos-7-for-nodejs) problem. So I installed NGINX and set it up so that it forwards the incoming requests on port 80 to port 300 by creating a `.conf` file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` location. Here is the configuration file.

```sh
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name xyz.xyz;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:300;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

But when I hit xyz.xyz I get the default page and when I go to xyz.xyz:300 I get my NodeJS app. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you listening on port 8080? Maybe you should listen on port 80?

Comment: Ow. No I was just trying random things. I was initially listening on 80.

Comment: 1. Did you restart nginx after added this file. 2. Is there line as `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;" on http { ... } scope where is at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

Comment: 1. Yes, multiple times
2. Yes there is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was an issue with SELinux.
I just ran this command and it worked.

```sh
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```